# How to get the indexOf an object within an AngularJS response object collection?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

## Use Case

I have a collection of objects returned from a REST request. Angular automatically populates each element with a `$$hashKey`. The problem is that when I search for an object in that array without the `$$hashKey`, it returns -1. This makes sense. Unfortunately, I don't have knowledge of the value of `$$hashKey`.

### Question

Is there a more effective way to search for an object within an object collection returned from a REST request in AngularJS without stripping out the `$$hashKey` property?

### Code

```
function arrayObjectIndexOf(arr, obj) {
var regex = /,?"\$\$hashKey":".*?",?/;
    var search = JSON.stringify(obj).replace(regex, '');
    console.log(search);
    for ( var i = 0, k = arr.length; i < k; i++ ){
        if (JSON.stringify(arr[i]).replace(regex, '') == search) {
            return i;
        }
    };
    return -1;
};
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`angular.equals()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals) does a deep comparison of objects without the `$` prefixed properties...

```
function arrayObjectIndexOf(arr, obj){
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(angular.equals(arr[i], obj)){
            return i;
        }
    };
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Simple and elegant! I really need to sit down and read through the whole Angular docs sometime.

Comment: Works great! Except I named mine: `indexOfObject` :)

Answer (score 5):

Since it's angular, why not use filtering:

$filter('filter')(pages, {id: pageId},true);

where pages is the array and id is the object property you want to match and pageId is the value you are matching with.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this is a bit ugly, but it's the simplest solution:

```
function arrayObjectIndexOf(arr, obj) {
    JSON.parse(angular.toJson(arr)).indexOf(obj)
}
```

The `angular.toJson` bit strips out any attributes with a leading $.  You might just want to store that clean object somewhere for searching.  Alternatively, you could write your own comparison stuff, but that's just bleh.

Answer (score 0):

Use lodash's find, where, filter to manipulate collections, check docs http://lodash.com/docs

Comment: Forgot to mention in the post that our lead programmer only allows us to use Angular.